# Expected value of $e^{X}$

Tags: self-study, expected-value

I am trying to find the expected value of $Y=e^{X}$ where the density of $X$ is $f(x) = 2x$ for $0<x<1$ (zero elsewhere). According to my textbook, the answer should be $2$.

I get the correct answer but I am a bit uncertain whether I am doing it the right way? So

$$E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1}g(x)f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\cdot2x\ dx = 2\int_{0}^{1} xe^{x}dx$$

and then I continue with selecting

$$u = x \quad \text{and} \quad dv = e^{x}$$

which results in $$du = dx \quad \text{and} \quad v = e^{x}.$$

Hence, one gets $$2\Big(\Big(xe^{x}\Big)_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}e^{x}dx\Big) = 2\Big(e - (e-1)\Big) = 2.$$

Is this the easiest solution? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: This should be the easiest way to do it analytically. Alternatively, if you know that $E(X) = 1$ for $X \sim \exp(1)$, then you may link this integration with $E(X)$.

Comment: @Solitary Huh? How is knowledge that the expectation of a standard exponential random variable has value $1$ related to the calculation that the OP needs to do (and has done correctly)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked, it's $e^x$, not $e^{-x}$... Anyway, I confirmed he is right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So that this does not remain an unanswered question, your calculations are correct, and there is no easier way of doing the calculations.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your downvote, In case you had not noticed, the **questions** asked were "Is there an easier way of doing this? Am I doing this correctly?" What other answer were you expecting?

Comment: @Alexis that's the difficulty with this sort of question (I brought this up on [meta in September](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/a-difficulty-with-self-study-like-questions-of-the-form-is-this-correct)) -- we're forced either to give an answer that's overly brief by the usual SE standard or to leave the question unanswered. Responses on whether a very short answer was okay were somewhat mixed.. Where an actual complete answer is really only one sentence and there's not much else that can be said, it's probably better to answer it with one sentence than not at all, ...ctd

Comment: ctd... but I think it's clear that if more can usefully be said it probably should. Finding something more to say is sometimes tricky.

Comment: @Glen_b, There really is nothing to be answered here except to say that what's been shown is right. Leaving the question unanswered means it will be thrown up repeatedly by Community as an unanswered question that deserves another look. So I answered it and marked my answer as `community wiki` so that I don't get reputation points for the answer. I notice that Moderator @Scortchi has expressed an opposite viewpoint in his answer to your question on meta and I am pinging him so that he can delete the answer above and convert it into a comment if he so wishes.

Comment: @Dilip I wasn't faulting your choices here in any way; I was trying to make it clear to Alexis that it's not necessarily wrong to answer it that way. Both of you should express your own thoughts in that meta thread (or vote if what you think has already been said and you haven't already done so).